# How to prove $P(A\cap B)=P(B) \implies P(A\cap B\cap C)=P(B\cap C)$

Tags: probability

How to prove $P(A\cap B)=P(B) \implies P(A\cap B\cap C)=P(B\cap C)$

I can see intuitively that B must be a subset of A and that would also imply $B\cap C$ is a subset of A. But how to prove it rigorously ?

Comment: $\mathbb P(A\cap B) = \mathbb P(B)$ doesn't imply that $B\subset A$. For a counterexample, let $\mathbb P$ be the restriction of Lebesgue measure to $[0,1]$, $A=(0,1]$, and $B=[0,1)$. Then $A\cap B=(0,1)$, so $\mathbb P(A)=\mathbb P(B) = \mathbb P(A\cap B)=1$, but neither $A\subset B$ nor $B\subset A$.

Comment: I should've added that I'm merely a highschool student and don't have high mathematical knowledge. This question was given in my text book and I couldn't find out a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the law of total probability, $$\mathbb P(B) = \mathbb P(B\cap A) + \mathbb P(B\cap A^c),$$ so $\mathbb P(B\cap A^c)=0$. Moreover, $$\mathbb P(B\cap C) = \mathbb P(B\cap C\cap A) + \mathbb P(B\cap C\cap A^c).$$ Since $B\cap C\cap A^c \subset B\cap A^c$, we must have $\mathbb P(B\cap C\cap A^c)=0$. Hence, $$\mathbb P(B\cap C)=\mathbb P(A\cap B\cap C),$$ as desired.